# php 500 Error on echo

Tags: echo

I'm always gettin a 500 internal server error on this line:

```
echo "<ul><li class='active'><a href='".substr($dir, 3)."/".$file."'><img src='".substr($dir, 3)."/"."small_".$file"' alt='small_".$file"'/></a></li></ul>";
```

what's going wrong there. I'm on Ubuntu VPS, php5.32 and apache2 are up to date and everything is set up correctly (I think so).
Thanks a lot for your help!
Greets,
jimmi

Answer (score 0):

**wiki quotes:**

> 500 - generic error message, given when no more specific message is
>   suitable

You do not have a `.` after `$file` in `img` and `alt`.
Try this:

```
echo "<ul><li class='active'><a href='".substr($dir, 3)."/".$file."'><img src='".substr($dir, 3)."/"."small_".$file."' alt='small_".$file."'/></a></li></ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 echo "<ul><li class='active'><a href='".substr($dir, 3)."/".$file."'><img src='".substr($dir, 3)."/"."small_".$file."' alt='small_".$file."'/></a></li></ul>";
```